# Rails Puma concurrency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, puma

I am trying to achieve concurrency in a rails puma server on development but am running into trouble.

My endpoint looks like:

```
    def show
      (1..10).each do |i|
        Rails.logger.info "I!! #{i}"
        sleep(1)
      end
      render json: {health: "hihi"}
    end
```

I run hit this endpoint twice, one after the other, and they run in sequence. Can I get them to be more concurrent?

Log:

```
    puma -t 2:16 -p 3000
    [20186] Puma starting in cluster mode...
    [20186] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
    [20186] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 16
    [20186] * Environment: development
    [20186] * Process workers: 2
    [20186] * Preloading application
    [20186] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
    [20186] Use Ctrl-C to stop
    [20186] - Worker 0 (pid: 20217) booted, phase: 0
    [20186] - Worker 1 (pid: 20218) booted, phase: 0

    Started GET "/v1/address-service/addresses/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-07 19:00:38 -0700
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
    Processing by Api::V1::AddressService::AddressesController#show as JSON
      Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
    I!! 1
    I!! 2
    I!! 3
    I!! 4
    I!! 5
    I!! 6
    I!! 7
    I!! 8
    I!! 9
    I!! 10
    Completed 200 OK in 10143ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)


    Started GET "/v1/address-service/addresses/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-07 19:00:49 -0700
    Processing by Api::V1::AddressService::AddressesController#show as JSON
      Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
    I!! 1
    I!! 2
    I!! 3
    I!! 4
    I!! 5
    I!! 6
    I!! 7
    I!! 8
    I!! 9
    I!! 10
    Completed 200 OK in 10031ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

development.rb:

```
  config.cache_classes=false
  config.allow_concurency = true
```

Comment: My rails version is: Rails 4.2.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize I was using chrome to test and it only sends one request at a time for what ever reason. I used curl and it works as expected.